# Displaying the Zoom-in cursor icon in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, mouse-cursor

How do I display the zoom-in cursor icon on IE11? `cursor:zoom-in` seems to have no effect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible as IE11 doesn't support `zoom-in` / `zoom-out` css cursor values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor